# Compile error on SPOJ site

Tags: java

I am trying to answer the following question. Tested on my IDE and it is compiling fine but on the site, it throws following error:

```
runtime error (NZEC) edit    ideone it
```

Please advice what am doing wrong.

[Link to SPOJ Site](http://www.spoj.com/problems/TEST/)

**Question**
rewrite small numbers from input to output. Stop processing input after reading in the number 42. All numbers at input are integers of one or two digits.

**Answer**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i = 0;

        while (i != 42){

            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            i = s.nextInt();
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not certain of what you're describing, but try move `  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);` to before the loop.

Comment: Those kind of site usally doesn't support the Scanner but provide a method to get the input. Search on the forum about that

Comment: Personal note : this question seems a bite old, the forum about this question is flood with non-english language, so you might not found any help. Here, this seems a bite random (some good answer aren't validated)

Comment: Try other question, more recent maybe. And see if there is some documentation about how to use there compiler. PS : Evan comment point out something that you should do

Comment: At least an explanation for `NZEC` can be found on the [SPOJ tutorial](http://www.spoj.com/tutorials/USERS/).